# How do you rename LINQ's name for when tables have a relationship with themselves?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, orm

Suppose I have a Person table that looks like this, where fk_FriendID is related to pk_PersonID:

[image]

LINQ2SQL will automatically map this as:

```
Person bert = new Person();
Person ernie = new Person();

bert.Person1 = ernie;
```

How do I overwrite this functionality so I can reference it as bert.Friend = ernie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest solution, but you  can add an additional property through a partial class:

```
partial class Person
{
   public Person Friend
   {
      get { return this.Person1; }
      set { this.Person1 = value; }
   }
}
```

This is also my standard procedure for putting strictly typed enum properties over numeric fields.

Any other solutions like mucking with the auto-generated code usually start to fall apart because you are constantly re-generating the code every time you make a schema change.

The option is to start using EF (I think they have this resolved there), but that's like trying to treat an itch on your arm by blowing it off with a shotgun.

Comment: Although phoog's answer was more correct techincally (for dealing with collections, like bert.Friends), this solves my simple syntax problem. Not that its a problem, but I like to write self documenting code that's easy to read. For that reason, this simpler approach is better suited. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386950.aspx it looks like you want to do this:

```
private EntitySet<Person> _Friends;
[Association(Storage = "_Friends", OtherKey = "PersonID")]
public EntitySet<Person> Friends
{
    get { return this._Friends; }
    set { this._Friends.Assign(value); }
}
```

EDIT:

To get to this through your .dbml file, use the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546179.aspx

The modification you need to make, as you can probably guess, is to search for "Person1" and replace it with "Friend" or "Friends" as appropriate.

Comment: I'm really new to LINQ2SQL. So far I've been relying on the .dbml and voodoo magic to turn DBs into objects. Where would this code go? I can't for the life of me find the auto-generated stuff in my MVC project.

Comment: @James: See edit for link to some documentation about modifying dbml files.